# Laravel livewire mount/save input field if others is selected

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How can I mount/save input field value if 'Others' is selected?

Controller:

```php
public Applicant $applicant;

public $eligibilityInput;

public function mount(Applicant $applicant)
{
    $this->applicant = $applicant;
    if ($this->applicant->eligibility === 'Others'){
        $this->applicant->eligibility = $this->eligibilityInput;
    }
}
```

Blade:

```html
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('applicant.eligibility') ? 'invalid' : '' }}">
    <label class="form-label required">{{ trans('cruds.applicant.fields.eligibility') }}</label>
    <select class="form-control" wire:model="applicant.eligibility">
        <option value="null" disabled>{{ trans('global.pleaseSelect') }}...</option>
        <option value="option1" >option1</option>
        <option value="option2" >option2</option>
        <option value="Others" >Others</option>
    </select>
    <div class="validation-message">
        {{ $errors->first('applicant.eligibility') }}
    </div>
    <div class="help-block">
        {{ trans('cruds.applicant.fields.eligibility_helper') }}
    </div>
    @if ($applicant->eligibility === 'Others')
        <div class="form-group"  style="display: block;">
            <label class="form-label required" for="eligibilityInput">Input Eligibility</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" wire:model="eligibilityInput" name="eligibilityInput" id="eligibilityInput" style="text-transform:uppercase">
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

When submitted, `Others` is saved when I need it to be the input field value. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to save down the `Others` value, but you use it to check in the view, you have to manipulate the data a little before you output it in `mount()` and also before saving it.

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so here's some example-code, I assume that the data is saved when the `save()` method is called.

Here we initially set the input-value from the `eligibility` property and the `eligibility` property to `Others` if the value was not in one of the valid options in the select.
Then, when you save the data, you need to go the other way around -- if the `eligibility` is equal to `Others`, then instead save the value from the input.

If you have more options that can be chosen from the select, then you need to update the array in `!in_array()` inside `mount()`.

```php
public function mount(Applicant $applicant)
{
    $this->applicant = $applicant;
    
    // Set the value of the input and fake the "Others" option selection
    if ($this->applicant->eligibility && !in_array($this->applicant->eligibility, ['option1', 'option2'])) {
        $this->eligibilityInput = $this->applicant->eligibility;
        $this->applicant->eligibility = 'Others';
    }
}

public function save()
{
    // When the value is Others, we actually save the input instead
    if ($this->applicant->eligibility === 'Others') {
        $this->applicant->eligibility = $this->eligibilityInput;
    }
    $this->applicant->save();
}
```

If you're not redirecting away after saving, you should probably reset the sate after saving, the same way its done in `mount()`, so that nothing changes for the user, something like this

```php
public function mount(Applicant $applicant)
{
    $this->applicant = $applicant;

    // Set the value of the input and fake the "Others" option selection
    if ($this->applicant->eligibility && !in_array($this->applicant->eligibility, ['option1', 'option2'])) {
        $this->eligibilityInput = $this->applicant->eligibility;
        $this->applicant->eligibility = 'Others';
    }
}

public function save()
{
    // When the value is Others, we actually save the input instead
    $resetState = false;
    if ($this->applicant->eligibility === 'Others') {
        $this->applicant->eligibility = $this->eligibilityInput;
        $resetState = true;
    }

    $this->applicant->save();

    if ($resetState) {
        $this->applicant->eligibility = 'Others';
    }
}
```